# cvCreateFileCapture()

Tags: c++, opencv

In the `Learning OpenCV` book, it the following is mentioned about this statement:

> ```
> CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture(argv[1]);
> ```
>
> The function `cvCreateFileCapture()` takes as its argument the name of the AVI file to be loaded and then returns a pointer to a `CvCapture` structure.

Can you just explain the sentence: "then returns a pointer to a `CvCapture` structure"?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. It means that you get a `CvCapture` pointer that can be used like one you get from `cvCaptureFromCAM` like so: `IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture)`.

Comment: Have you actually read the this statement in its whole context, and this with some basic C knowledge, of course?

Answer (score 2):

It just allocates a new `CvCapture` structure and returns a pointer to this structure. You don't really access the fields of this structure but pass the pointer to other functions that work on the file capture, like `cvQueryFrame` or `cvSetCaptureProperty`. And don't forget to free the resources with `cvReleaseCapture` when you're done with the file.

This shouldn't be too hard to understand with some basic C-knowledge, especially with respect that many OpenCV function work this way.

By the way, as your question is tagged C++, consider using the C++-interface of OpenCV, which abstracts many of those things away. Although there is no real book for it, only for the C-interface.