# C++ - pointer value

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

In the `Learning OpenCV` book:

```
.
.
CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture(argv[1]);
IplImage* frame;
while(1)
{
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
.
.
}
```

Here, we can see that `*frame` is a pointer. But, when we write the following `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);`, we are not assigning an address to the pointer. What exactly will the values be that `frame` will hold in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: actually, when we see ..., we **are** assigning an address to the pointer.

Comment: `frame` is a pointer; `*frame` is an `IplImage`

Comment: possible duplicate of [cvCreateFileCapture()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777872/cvcreatefilecapture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frame` is pointer to an object of type `IplImage`. Presumably, the `cvQueryFrame()` function allocates an `IplImage` object and returns the address of this object. The statement

```
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

assigns the value of this returned pointer to `frame`. If indeed the function is allocating a new object you'll probably be required to free this memory later by calling `operator delete` or some function like

```
void cvDestroyFrame( IplImage * );
```

Also the statement you make at the end of your question ("`*frame` is a pointer") is not accurate - `frame` is a pointer; `*frame` means you're de-referencing the pointer which makes its type `IplImage`.

Comment: When you say  for `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);`: *assigns the value of this returned pointer to frame*. Why did you say a returned pointer? The pointer is `frame` isn't it? Where is the returned pointer? Shouldn't we say the returned address? Thanks

Comment: The `cvQueryFrame()` function returns a pointer by value. This pointer contains (or points to) the address of the new allocated `IplImage` object. The returned value is copied over to `frame`. That's why I worded it the way I did, but it's probably OK to think of it as returning an address too.

Comment: The function cvQueryFrame is returning a pointer, which frame is being set to.

Answer (score 2):

> But, when we write the following frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);, we
>   are not assigning an address to the pointer.

Actually we **are** assigning address to the pointer. `cvQueryFrame` returns pointer value (address).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `*frame` is a dereferenced pointer that will give the object pointed to by the pointer `frame`.  In this case, the function `cvQueryFrame()` is returning a pointer that is being assigned to `frame`.

Comment: Can you just explain how `cvQueryFrame()` is returning a pointer? Isn't it returning an address? Thanks

Comment: A pointer is a memory address that points to an object of a specific type.  You will often hear that function returns a "pointer" (to a speicifc object).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a prototype of cvQueryFrame (I'm not familiar with this library), I'm going to assume its return type is of IplImage*.  What this method is probably doing is allocating some memory within itself and then returning the address from the allocation.  So you are in reality, setting to an address.

Answer (score 1):

The function `cvQueryFrame` returns a pointer to `IplImage`, that means your code does assign an address to the pointer. Here is the signature of the function:

```
IplImage* cvQueryFrame( CvCapture* capture );
```

Read about it in the manual:

- [HighGUI Reference Manual](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm)